# See Create database queries by modelBuilder

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-model-builder

currently I am working at a project which requires to be backwards compatible with (non-EF) databases, but also want to create a new database from model.

For this task I save the current schema somewhere (in XML form) and update the databases with raw sql update steps, until they match the schema, which is working fine.

Also, the modelBuilder matches the schema (as in, my algorithm finds no difference between the newly created database by context.Database.Create() and my saved schema) **currently**.

Since the schema will most likely change in later stages of development, I do have to support **two ways** to create an Up-to-date database and was wondering if I could combine these two - since now I have to update the saved target schema, create the update steps AND update my modelBuilder so that is creates exactly the database I need - which would be quite a tedious task.

So since there is probably no way to "translate" my schema to modelBuilder entries and because there is more not mapped information in my POCO classes (which prohibits the approach of updating a correct database and update my classes database first) the only (visible to me) way would be to somehow gather the CREATE TABLE statements a context would create when I call Database.Create() which I can use to update my schema and the update steps accordingly.

I know quite sure I can do the same by logging the context while calling the Create() method, however - this will take quite some time, will issue some queries I do not need and will create a dump database I have to get rid of afterwards each time I update my model.

So I was wondering if there was a way to inspect the modelBuilder (or the context, of course) and somehow see what the tables would look like it maps to.

Comment: I'd rather use a schema difference viewer like Redgate's SQL Compare, or a Visual Studio database project.

Comment: unfortunately, this won't fly, as these are heterogenous databases (for example, SQLCe 3.5, SQLCE 4.0, SQL Server, I do not have the target database... and the comparisons won't really help me, as I am fully aware what changes have to be done when I'm writing an update script. I just would like a possibility to map this to the modelBuilder.